# How do I install an MSI synchronously?

Tags: windows, windows-installer

To do an unattended installation of any MSI package, one can simply use the following command:

```
msiexec /qn /i package.msi
```

However, this triggers an asynchronous installation: if you happen to chain 2 dependent installations, you will have to wait somehow for the 1st installation to complete.

Is there a way to do this from the command line ?

Answer (score 8):

I've had luck with this:

```
start /wait msiexec /i MyInstaller.msi ...
```

Found in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2005/11/15/493236.aspx) from 2005. Hope you found it way back in '08.

Comment: Lol this post just hilarious haha.... but anyways here's the without the "alias" commands, I was getting positional parameter errors: `Start-Process -Wait -FilePath msiexec -ArgumentList /i, "c:\package.msi", /qn`

Answer (score 3):

We'd run into this a number of times with various products and I'd ended up using a small outer program that launches each msi and waits until it finishes to start the next one. You can probably do this in something as lightweight as a vbscript, but at the time we wanted a bit more gui so we had a larger outer program.